# Finding MAC address with OUI List

Tags: cisco-ios, mac-address

I'm in the process of labeling the interfaces of my Cisco 3750G with descriptions referencing the device type that is associated with that port.

I understand that I am able to run a `show mac address-table | i 0010` , which will find the interface associated with that mac address as shown below

```
3750G#show mac address-table | i 0010
 All                      STATIC      CPU
   1    0010.xxxx.xxxx    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/7
   1    0010.xxxx.xxxx    DYNAMIC     Gi2/0/10
   1    0010.xxxx.xxxx    DYNAMIC     Gi5/0/27
   1    0010.xxxx.xxxx    DYNAMIC     Gi3/0/20
```

Since manufacturers can have multiple OUI's, is there a way to run that list of possible OUIs with just one command instead of having to copy and paste, changing the variable after the `| include` every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While searching, I found that you're able to pipe multiple variables within the same single command.

For example, if I look for the OUIs of the MAC addresses with a prefix of 0010, 33ca, and 8819 I can use  the following command to filter out just those mac addresses with the matching prefixes.

*MAC addresses UAA omitted for security*

```
3750G#show mac address-table | i 0010|38ca|8819
   1    0010.xxxx.xxxx     DYNAMIC     Gi2/0/3
   1    38ca.xxxx.xxxx     DYNAMIC     Gi4/0/13
   1    8819.xxxx.xxxx     DYNAMIC     Gi4/0/13
   1    8819.xxxx.xxxx     DYNAMIC     Gi4/0/13
   2    0010.xxxx.xxxx     DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/20
```